# Mysql filas a columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla (llamada load_zone_prom) con 3 columnas: fecha, zona_carga, valor.
Si hago un select `( SELECT distinct fecha, zona_carga, AVG(truncate(pml_mda,2)) as valor FROM npa.load_zone_prom where zona_carga='ACAPULCO' and fecha between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' group by fecha)` para que sea un solo año, devuelve algo asi:

```
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |       fecha     |    zona_carga   |    valor  |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-01-01     |    Acapulco     |    13     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-02-01     |    Acapulco     |    15     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-03-01     |    Acapulco     |    14     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-04-01     |    Acapulco     |    13     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-05-01     |    Acapulco     |    10     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-06-01     |    Acapulco     |    10     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-07-01     |    Acapulco     |    10     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-08-01     |    Acapulco     |    14     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-09-01     |    Acapulco     |    15     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-10-01     |    Acapulco     |    16     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-11-01     |    Acapulco     |    19     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
   |  2020-12-01     |    Acapulco     |    20     |
   +-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

¿Cómo consulto la base de datos para devolver algo como esto?

Locational Marginal Price (LMP) - NP Analytics
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

1.Primero debés pasar el timestamp a nombre: [MySQL convert month number to month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213427/mysql-convert-month-number-to-month-name)

2.Luego debés pivotear por ese nuevo campo. Cómo Mysql no tiene pivot vas a tener que hacer algo como esto: [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)